# Updating UI Elements from within a Command Action

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, icommand

If I update a UI element multiple times from within a command action, only the last change is shown. As far as I understand it this has to do with the fact that the command actions are not performed in the UI thread but I fail to understand how to correctly command the UI thread to update the control at the time I want it updated.

This is the situation:

A `TextBlock` and a `Button` bound to the values in the code-behind file (this is only for testing purposes, I use MVVM in production):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
<Button Content="Test"
        Command="{Binding Command}" />
```

`Command` is a simple `RelayCommand` executing the following action:

```
private void ChangeText()
{
    Text = "Text 1";

    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    Text = "Text 2";

    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    Text = "Text 3";
}
```

The program simply sleeps for the prescribed two seconds and displays *Text 3* in the text box, the first two UI changes are ignored. I want it to first display *Text 1*, sleep for a second, display *Text 2*, sleep again for a second and then finally display *Text 3*.

I guess there is a very simple way to achieve this and but I haven't found a suitable answer so far here or anywhere else.

Answer (score 3):

On the contrary, command actions **are** performed on the UI thread unless moved otherwise, and that's your problem.

`Thread.Sleep` is blocking the UI thread, so it can't do anything to display the updates. Instead use `Task.Delay` so the method execution is no longer blocking the UI thread (this also prevents the application from appearing "frozen"):

```
private async void ChangeText()
{
    Text = "Text 1";
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Text = "Text 2";
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Text = "Text 3";
}
```